# Pests infestation in bathroom - identification and termination

Tags: pest-control

Roughly every night, these strange pests are crawling all over our master bathroom, mainly close to the ceiling. By morning time they're usually gone or I find some of their bodies scattered on the floor.
I've already hired an exterminator which has sprayed the exterior of the house and inside our bathroom, but they're still here. Also tried spraying along the walls with ortho home defense insect killer. I have only seen them in the master bathroom.
Can anyone identify these? Our home is very clean. What are they looking for, and how do I stop them from coming in?
We live in Irvine, CA
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Collect some in a bottle and take to a pest control company.  Or photograph them at higher magnification and use internet to Identify. Could be termites.

Comment: I agree that termites is the likely identification.

Comment: Looks like there are some gaps between the wall and ceiling.  Also agree - have them examined.  If termites, immediate PROFESSIONAL action should be taken.

Comment: Internet says these are winged ants, not termites

Comment: is there access from the bathroom ceiling to attic space? eg a fan or loosely fitting pot lights? might want to check up there. flying ants swarm to mate, if they're swarming outside, some might be crawling in somehow. another thing to check is for leaking water, insects are attracted to moisture in the bathroom.

Comment: @Dandan https://www.orkin.com/termites/life-cycle/flying-termites/ not saying that is definitely what they are in your case, but they do exist

Answer (score 1):

I have found cases where flying insects are getting in at the bathroom vent when it was just pumping into the attic space on several occasions 2 cases were lady bugs and 1 was small beatles. 
I have also seen them coming in at fireplace's where the stone work to wall was not fully sealed but since yours are in the bath I would check the vent fan and make sure it is vented to the outside and has a back draft damper. After that seal any cracks at the corners of your walls , and where your plumbing enters and exits even under the tub drain expanding foam is great to fill openings where water and drain pipes enter.